# Meaning of the mapping

Tags: notation

I am reading basic sets. In the section of sesquilinear mapping,
I came across this mapping
 $f: X \to X^*$ 
 i.e  $x \ $ maps to $ (x|.)$

Here I know $X$ is a function space, I guess
$X^*$ stands for its dual. $(|)$ is inner mapping.

My question:  What exactly is $(x|.)$?

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: It's the linear functional $(x |\cdot ): y\mapsto (x|y)$.  At least, this is what I would say if $X$ was a vector space and $X^\ast$ is dual space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the map

$$\begin{array} .(x\:|\:\cdot): & X & \to & \mathbb{C} \\
 & y & \mapsto & (x|y) \end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is now clear.